# What are examples of "LOCC linked" quantum instruments?

Tags: entanglement, quantum-operation, locc-operation

Define a *quantum instrument* $\mathfrak J$ as a collection of *completely positive* (CP) maps $(\mathcal E_j:j\in\Theta)\subset\mathrm{CP}(\mathcal H)$, such that $\sum_j \mathcal E_j$ is also trace-preserving (and thus a channel/CPTP map).
Denote the set of all such *quantum instruments* with $\mathrm{CP}[\Theta]$.

As explained in ([*Chitambar et al. 2012*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.4583)), quantum instruments can be used to define the different classes of *LOCC instruments*. More precisely, they say that an instrument $\mathfrak J'$ is ***LOCC linked*** to $\mathfrak J\equiv(\mathcal A_1,\mathcal A_2,...)$ if there exists a collection of one-way local instruments $\{\mathfrak J_j^{(K_j)}=(\mathcal B_{1|j},\mathcal B_{2|j},...): j=1,2,...\}$ such that $\mathfrak I'$ is a coarse-graining of the instrument with CP maps $\mathcal B_{j'|j}\circ\mathcal A_j$.

Here, an instrument $\mathfrak J^{(K)}=(\mathcal F_1,\mathcal F_2,...)$ is called *one-way local* with respect to a party $K$ if each of its CP maps has the form $\mathcal F_j=(\bigotimes_{J\neq K}\mathcal T_j^{(J)})\otimes \mathcal E_j^{(K)}$ where $\mathcal E^{(K)}$ is a CP map on $\mathcal B(\mathcal H^{A_k})$, and for each $J\neq K$, $\mathcal T_j^{(J)}$ is some trace-preserving CP map.

While formally precise, this definition is quite abstract and a bit hard to parse; some examples would probably make it much easier to digest.

What are some examples of *LOCC-linked* quantum instruments? Examples of instruments in some $\mathrm{LOCC}_r$ class, and outside of them, would also both be appreciated.